# Bootstrap column weirdness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So for some reason my columns are stacking really oddly when I reduce the browser size.  I have three Columns each with unordered lists inside them but when the browser is reduced the columns height becomes nonexistent and they end up on top of each other.  I wonder if its either because im floating the elements left and right or maybe because i edited the webkit padding and margin on the ul.

[Imgr album of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cIlk.jpg)

This is what I have

```
<section class="details-contain greySpace-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <h1>Timeline:</h1>
                    <li>3 Months</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="center-block">
                    <h1>Role:</h1>
                    <li>Design and Front-end Dev</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <h1>Programs:</h1>
                    <li>Photoshop</li>
                    <li>Illustrator</li>
                    <li>Brackets</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.details-contain{
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.greySpace-box{
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #575757;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #575757;
    z-index: 5;
}

.greySpace-box p{
    color: white;
}

.greySpace-box li{
    color: white;
}

.greySpace-box h1{
    color: white;
}

h1{
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: "utopia-std";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
}

ul li{
    color: #7e7e7e;
    font-family: "museo-sans";
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
}

ul{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `pull-right` and `pull-left` classes and your grid will behave properly.

If you want `Programs` right-aligned, add the following class to your `css`

```
.alignRight{

text-align: right;
list-style-position: inside;

}
```

And apply it to the desired column.

Your markup would then be

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <h1>Timeline:</h1>
                    <li>3 Months</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="center-block">
                    <h1>Role:</h1>
                    <li>Design and Front-end Dev</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 alignRight">
                <ul>
                    <h1>Programs:</h1>
                    <li>Photoshop</li>
                    <li>Illustrator</li>
                    <li>Brackets</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Here's a demo](http://www.bootply.com/DocevWawbq) to illustrate.

Comment: Problem is that the final column isnt floating right and it then looks odd.

Comment: @rikuto148 what do you mean it "looks odd"? Floating right is the cause of your problem. Check [my updated demo](http://www.bootply.com/DocevWawbq) to see if we're getting closer.

Comment: Yep that solves the problem.  So im supposed to use align-right?

Comment: @rikuto148 yes, as well as `list-style-position: inside;`; check my updated answer.

Comment: I figured it out.  Im going to float the ui right, then at a certain break point float it left.